# Mesh is invisible and only shows in edit mode

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I'm pretty new to blender and I've been trying to put a Mesh onto a skeleton with animations (keyframes) but I've ran into the issue of my Mesh disappearing after adding it to the skeleton with animations.

I can see the mesh perfectly fine in edit mode but I can't play the animation with the mesh attached. I've tried a couple of solutions but none have worked (Auto run python scripts is on,Went into pose mode and applied pose as rest shape,and a couple of other things).

Sorry if the terms I'm using are wrong I'm still very new to blender and anything related to it.  Here's the file   [Stalker Animation and Mesh](https://www.mediafire.com/file/63v36d0bgzqfdtl/IdleStalkerMeshNotShowing.blend)    *(The model and skeleton are .nif files I took from falloutnv and the animation i'm trying to use is a .kf file,I've used the other version of blender with the nif attachment to send them over to the most current version of blender)*

If someone can give me instructions on how to fix this issue I would be grateful,I want to import other animations but I want to make sure I'm doing it right.